# Python Division Of Complex Numbers Without Using Built In Types and Operators

Tags: python, division, complex-numbers, built-in-types

I have to implement a class called `ComplexNumbers` which is representing a complex number and I'm **not allowed** to use the **built in types** for that.
I already have overwritten the operators (`__add__`, `__sub__`, `__mul__`, `__abs__`, `__str_` which allows to perform basic operations.
But now I'm stuck with overwriting the `__div__` operator.

Allowed to use:

I'm using `float` to represent the imaginary part of the number and `float` to represent the rel part.

What I have already tried:

- I looked up how to perform a division of complex numbers (handwritten)
- I have done an example calculation
- Thought about how to implement it programatically without any good result

Explanation of how to divide complex numbers:

http://www.mathwarehouse.com/algebra/complex-number/divide/how-to-divide-complex-numbers.php

My implementation of multiply:

```
 def __mul__(self, other):
        real = (self.re * other.re - self.im * other.im)
        imag = (self.re * other.im + other.re * self.im)
        return ComplexNumber(real, imag)
```

Comment: Are you not allowed to use `int` ?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I will update the question type of the real part is `float` the type of the imaginary part is `int`

Comment: Okay, that's all you need anyways.  Where in the division algorithm did you run into trouble?

Comment: Can you show us your __mul__ or add so we can copy your style.

Comment: @DanielLee updated post

Comment: Why is the imaginary part restricted to `int`?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I tried to implement like it is shown in the link of the post. I know how to calculate the numerator and the denominator  (step 1: Determine the conjugate of the denominator) but in the end I'm stuck again with a division

Comment: @chepner your right it should be `float`

Comment: The key insight is that the denominator will always be real, after you multiply by the conjugate over itself (I recommend that you prove this to yourself.).  Then you can change `(x+yi)/z` to `(x/z) + ((y/z)i)`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Ty, now I got a glue, I need to calculate the denominator first and than I can simply divide to the real and imaginary part

Comment: Yep.  Don't forget to also multiply the conjugate of the denominator with the numerator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should suffice:

```
def conjugate(self):
    # return a - ib

def __truediv__(self, other):
    other_into_conjugate = other * other.conjugate()
    new_numerator = self * other.conjugate()
    # other_into_conjugate will be a real number
    # say, x. If a and b are the new real and imaginary
    # parts of the new_numerator, return (a/x) + i(b/x)

__floordiv__ = __truediv__
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the tips of @PatrickHaugh I was able to solve the problem. Here is my solution:

```
  def __div__(self, other):
        conjugation = ComplexNumber(other.re, -other.im)
        denominatorRes = other * conjugation
        # denominator has only real part
        denominator = denominatorRes.re
        nominator = self * conjugation
        return ComplexNumber(nominator.re/denominator, nominator.im/denominator)
```

Calculating the conjugation and than the denominator which has no imaginary part.