# Python - How can I divide a number by a complex number, implementing my own class for complex numbers?

Tags: python, class, methods, division, complex-numbers

I'm currently implementing my own class for Complex numbers like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144760/python-division-of-complex-numbers-without-using-built-in-types-and-operators/60562578#60562578). And thanks to this post I manage to did it for division between 2 complex numbers.

But I still got a issue : I understand that `4 / (42i + 4)` and `(42i + 4) / 4` are not the same but in my case I will obtain the same result. It's because the programm will take the number alone as an integer in this case and it will not be able to divide an integer by my Complex object.

I understand I need to create an __rdiv__ method to handle this. 
I already did that for other basic operations (__add__, __sub__, __mul__) by doing this :

```py
class Complex(object):
    def __init__(self, real=0, imag=0):
        self.real = real
        self.imag = imag

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Complex(self.real + other.real,
                       self.imag + other.imag)

    def __radd__(self, other):
        return self.__add__(other) 

    def __sub__(self, other):
        print(self, other)
        return Complex(self.real - other.real,
                       self.imag - other.imag)

    def __rsub__(self, other):
        return self.__sub__(other)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        # print(self, other)
        return Complex(self.real*other.real - self.imag*other.imag,
                       self.imag*other.real + self.real*other.imag)

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        return self.__mul__(other)
```

But I cannot use the same logic with division. Maybe the maths should be different, but I cannot get my head around it. Could someone help me on that ? Thanks a lot

Here's my __div__ :

```py
def __div__(self, other):
    conjugation = Complex(other.real, -other.imag)
    denominatorRes = other * conjugation
    denominator = float(denominatorRes.real)
    nominator = self * conjugation
    try:
        return Complex(nominator.real/denominator, nominator.imag/denominator)
    except ZeroDivisionError as e:
        print e
        return None
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def __truediv__(self, other):
    return Complex((self.real * other.real + self.imag * other.imag) / (other.real ** 2 + other.imag ** 2), (self.imag * other.real - self.real * other.imag) / (other.real ** 2 + other.imag ** 2))
```

source: [wolfram mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexDivision.html)

Comment: Hi, unfortuntely I got the same problem : `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'Complex'`

Comment: So my problem is actually on \__div__ but also on \__sub__ , when I use FIRST : an int/float and SECOND : a Complex. Only  on \__rdiv__ and on \__sub__ because the order matters : `x - y ≠ y - x` and `x / y ≠ y / x` which is not the case with \__add__ and \__mul__  because : `x + y = y + x` and `x * y = y * x`

Comment: Your implementation for subtraction is correct, my implementation of division works as long as both inputs are Complex (both of the Complex type)

Comment: Unfortunately this was not what I needed. I needed to do some calcul between real numbers and complex numbers. But thanks anyway for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Done !

The problem was not about the maths but about my logic.
Here's my code :

````py
class Complex(object):
    def __init__(self, real=0, imag=0):
        self.real = real
        self.imag = imag

    def __add__(self, other):
        # if isinstance(other, (float,int)):
        #   other = Complex(other)
        return Complex(self.real + other.real,
                       self.imag + other.imag)

    def __radd__(self, other):
        return self.__add__(other) 

    def __mul__(self, other):
        # if isinstance(other, (float,int)):
        #   other = Complex(other)
        return Complex(self.real*other.real - self.imag*other.imag,
                       self.imag*other.real + self.real*other.imag)

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        return self.__mul__(other)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, (float,int)):
            other = Complex(other)
        return Complex(self.real - other.real,
                       self.imag - other.imag)

    def __rsub__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, (float,int)):
            other = Complex(other)
        return other.__sub__(self)

    def __div__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, (float,int)):
            other = Complex(other)
        s1, s2, o1, o2 = self.real, self.imag, other.real, other.imag
        r = float(o1**2 + o2**2)
        try: 
            return Complex((s1*o1+s2*o2)/r, (s2*o1-s1*o2)/r)
        except ZeroDivisionError as e:
            print e
            return None

    def __rdiv__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, (float,int)):
            other = Complex(other)
        return other.__div__(other)
    ```
````