# How to not repeat element in a list?

Tags: arrays, list, flutter, dart, printing

I am facing a problem which is that I have a set and I want to not repeat element inside.

I have used .contains but it didn't actually work.

My code :

```dart
void main() {
  Set<Text> mySet = {};

  if (!mySet.contains(Text('mohamed', 1))) {
    mySet.add(Text('mohamed', 1));
    mySet.add(Text('mohamed', 1));
  }

  print(mySet);
}

class Text {
  String name;
  int number;

  Text(name, number);
}
```

Output:

{Instance of 'Text', Instance of 'Text'}

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/228523/duplicate-class-objects-in-a-set

Answer (score 0):

Each time you add a new `Text` instance to the set.  As far as the set is concerned, each text instance is distinct.

Referring to https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.0/dart-core/Set-class.html:

> The default Set implementation, LinkedHashSet, considers objects indistinguishable if they are equal with regard to operator Object.==.

You may override the `==` operator (https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#overridable-operators) to assist the Set implementation with distinguishing between the instances.

```
class Text {
  String name;
  int number;

  Text(name, number);

  bool operator ==(Text otherInstance) {
    return this.number == otherInstance.number
      && this.name == otherInstance.name;
  }

  // thank's to lrn's catch
  int get hashCode => name.hashCode ^ number.hashCode;
}
```

Refer to this stackoverflow post for more examples on the topic: [Does dart support operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130472/does-dart-support-operator-overloading).

**UPDATE (10/28/19)**

To avoid getting lost in a comment, taking [lrn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2156621/lrn)'s recommendation, tagging on:

```
int get hashCode => name.hashCode ^ number.hashCode;
```

Additional References:

- https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/hash_and_equals.html

Comment: If you override `==` in this way, you *must* also override `hashCode` to provide a value that is consistent with `==`. For example, here it could be `int get hashCode => name.hashCode ^ number.hashCode;`

Comment: Merci! Updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [Equatable](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable) library to simplify the process.

Then you only need to extend Equatable like this

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

void main() {
  Set<Text> mySet = {};

  if (!mySet.contains(Text('mohamed', 1))) {
    mySet.add(Text('mohamed', 1));
    mySet.add(Text('mohamed', 1));
  }

  for (var s in mySet) {
    print(s.name);
  }
}

class Text extends Equatable {
  final String name;
  final int number;

  Text(this.name, this.number);
}
```