# Accept object as an function

Tags: dart

Is there any way in Dart to accept an object as a function?

I am looking for some operator or type that can replace **`+/*()=>*/`** with some other operator without changing the expected functionality if that those operators would have not been commented

For example:

```
class Test {
  operator +([...])=>[...];
}

void main() {
  Test test = Test();
  int a = 3;
  var func = test + /*()=>*/ a;
  print(func()); // should print 3
  ++a;
  print(func()); // should print 4
}
```

Comment: You mean, you want to overload an operator in Dart?

Comment: Yes, but in a specific way

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does dart support operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130472/does-dart-support-operator-overloading)

Comment: No, I know that Dart supports operator overloading but this question targets a specific use-case of operator-overloading as described in the question.

Comment: I am looking for some operator or type that can replace `+/*()=>*/` with some other operator without changing the expected functionality if that those operators would have not been commented

Comment: Do you mean something like this `var func = () => text + a;`?