# How to remove items from list if list stores a model class?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am using List and storing my model class items in it. Adding model class item in list is working fine but removal is not working.

My Code is:

```
 _selectedTeachersList.remove(MemberModel(
                              docID: _teachersList[i].docID,
                              memberID: _teachersList[i].regNo,
                              memberName: _teachersList[i].firstName +
                                  " " +
                                  _teachersList[i].lastName));
```

Kindly guide me where I am doing wrong.
Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130472/does-dart-support-operator-overloading you can check this link it should solve your problem. Other thing  you can do is to use equatable package for object equality.

Comment: For remove any item you simply need to pass index of item, you don't need to define complete model in remove.