# How do i define < operator on dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

when i run the program,it shows "Failed to build basics1_dart:basics1_dart:
bin/basics1_dart.dart:38:12: Error: The operator '<' isn't defined for the class 'String?'.
Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '<' operator.
if(num1<0)"
what should i do

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does dart support operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130472/does-dart-support-operator-overloading)

Comment: It won't work because you're trying to use `<` on a nullable type.  Convert it to a non-nullable type first.  For example: `if (num1 != null && num1 < 0)`

Comment: It is possible to define `<` operator as an extension method on `String?`. But I think that  @jamesdlin's suggestion is more likely to be the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about `String?` type, which is a `String` with added possibility to contain `null` value.

Here under the question is a comment from @jamesdlin, it possible could be an answer, but operator `<` does not exist also for a `String` type. There is a [compareTo](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.2/dart-core/String/compareTo.html) function, which can be used instead to compare it with other String: `if (num1 != null && num1.compareTo("0") < 0)`

You can easily compare Your value in case of it does not actually contain the `null`. As have said @jamesdlin, You can compare you value with null first, but if You are sure it is not null, also You can use `!` operator to write compact cast of Your value to not nullable: `if (num1!.compareTo("0") < 0)`. This cast will throw an exception when it is null, but if You sure - why not?

Also I wonder why Your `num1` variable is a nullable string while You compare it with a number? May be You need to cast to a numeric type first? You can use `int.parse(String)` to do this, and store parsed integer value in another variable, or use it once for comparing `if (int.parse(num1!) < 0)`